# jquery validator for fields with name attribute ending with?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
<input id="j_id0:mainFormId:selected:selectedProductsDiv:3:quantityId" name="j_id0:mainFormId:selected:selectedProductsDiv:3:quantityId" type="text">
```

How do I attach jquery validator rule for the above field? All the examples are showing that we need to simply put the name attribute but in my case the name attribute keeps changing but it always ends with quantityId..

```
        j$('form[id$="mainFormId"]').validate({
            rules: {
                $quantityId : "required"
            }

        });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can use `addMethod` and use the method name as a class also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the rules with code:

```
var rules = {};
$("form[id$=mainformId] input[name$=quantityId]").each(function() {
    rules[this.name] = "required";
});
$('form[id$="mainFormId"]').validate({
    rules: rules
});
```